# Why is all the Data in the XML file deleted when attempting to Update/ Delete one row via a Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview

I have an Editable Gridview, which functions off of an XML file. When I attempt to Update/Delete a row via the Gridiview, all the data in the XML file is then deleted. When I insert a new row, the pending data is replaced w/ the new row. Could I please get some direction as to what I'm doing wrong? I provided my xml file and the four methods used for editing the GridView.

The XML:

```
<root>
    <pos>
        <partNumbers>
            <partid>0</partid>
            <partnumber>796542</partnumber>
        </partNumbers>
        <partNumbers>
            <partid>1</partid>
            <partnumber>225614</partnumber>
        </partNumbers>
        <partNumbers>
            <partid>2</partid>
            <partnumber>123457</partnumber>
        </partNumbers>
    </pos>
</root>
```

The Source Code -C#-:

```
//Bind Data
    protected void BindGridView()
    {
        DataSet dsgvPartNumber = new DataSet();
        dsgvPartNumber.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
        gvPartNumber.DataSource = dsgvPartNumber.Tables["partNumbers"];
        gvPartNumber.DataBind();
        gvPartNumber.ShowFooter = true;
    }
    //Delete
    protected void gvPartNumber_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        BindGridView();
        DataTable dsgvPartNumberDelete = (DataTable)gvPartNumber.DataSource;
        dsgvPartNumberDelete.Rows[gvPartNumber.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItemIndex].Delete();
        dsgvPartNumberDelete.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
        BindGridView();

    }

//Update GridView
    protected void gvPartNumber_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = gvPartNumber.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItemIndex;
        string partId = ((TextBox)gvPartNumber.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPartID")).Text;
        string partNumber = ((TextBox)gvPartNumber.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPartNumber")).Text;
        gvPartNumber.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGridView();
        DataTable dtUpdateXMLFile = (DataTable)gvPartNumber.DataSource;
        dtUpdateXMLFile.Rows[index]["partid"] = partId;
        dtUpdateXMLFile.Rows[index]["partnumber"] = partNumber;
        dtUpdateXMLFile.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
        BindGridView();

    }

//Insert New Row
    protected void gvPartNumber_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "insertXMLData")
        {
            string partid = ((TextBox)gvPartNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPartIDInsert")).Text;
            string partnumber = ((TextBox)gvPartNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPartNumberInsert")).Text;
            BindGridView();
            DataTable dtXMLInsert = (DataTable)gvPartNumber.DataSource;
            DataRow drInsert = dtXMLInsert.NewRow();
            drInsert["partid"] = partid;
            drInsert["partnumber"] = partnumber;
            dtXMLInsert.Rows.Add(drInsert);
            dtXMLInsert.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
            BindGridView();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Step through the code. You're probably writing an empty string to the xml file or something. Find out why it's empty... what diagnostic efforts have you attempted? I see none.

Comment: Does putting `dtXMLInsert.AcceptChanges();` before `dtXMLInsert.WriteXml` helps?

Comment: There's no need for tags in titles. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you are saving your datatable to xml file which is wrong:

```
    DataTable dtUpdateXMLFile = (DataTable)gvPartNumber.DataSource;
    dtUpdateXMLFile.Rows[index]["partid"] = partId;
    dtUpdateXMLFile.Rows[index]["partnumber"] = partNumber;
    dtUpdateXMLFile.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
```

Remember, this table is only from a part of your xml file(there is another table, pos). Actually you have to save the dataset, not this table. First update the table to the dataset, then save it. your methods may look like:

```
//Delete
protected void gvPartNumber_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    BindGridView();
    DataSet dsgvPartNumber = new DataSet();
    dsgvPartNumber.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
    dsgvPartNumber.Tables["partNumbers"].Rows[gvPartNumber.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItemIndex].Delete();
    dsgvPartNumber.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
    BindGridView();

}

//Update GridView
protected void gvPartNumber_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int index = gvPartNumber.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItemIndex;
    string partId = ((TextBox)gvPartNumber.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPartID")).Text;
    string partNumber = ((TextBox)gvPartNumber.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPartNumber")).Text;
    gvPartNumber.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGridView();

    DataSet dsgvPartNumber = new DataSet();
    dsgvPartNumber.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
    dsgvPartNumber.Tables["partNumbers"].Rows[index]["partid"] = partId;
    dsgvPartNumber.Tables["partNumbers"].Rows[index]["partnumber"] = partNumber;
    dsgvPartNumber.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
    BindGridView();

}

//Insert New Row
protected void gvPartNumber_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "insertXMLData")
    {
        string partid = ((TextBox)gvPartNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPartIDInsert")).Text;
        string partnumber = ((TextBox)gvPartNumber.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPartNumberInsert")).Text;
        BindGridView();
        DataTable dtXMLInsert = (DataTable)gvPartNumber.DataSource;

        DataSet dsgvPartNumber = new DataSet();
        dsgvPartNumber.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
        DataRow drInsert = dsgvPartNumber.Tables["partNumbers"].NewRow(); 
        drInsert["partid"] = partid;
        drInsert["partnumber"] = partnumber;
        dsgvPartNumber.Tables["partNumbers"].Rows.Add(drInsert);
        dsgvPartNumber.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/xml/storeUserInfo.xml"));
        BindGridView();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out what I was doing wrong and for the explanation. It's functioning now, thanks again.